# How do I create an instance of a class from the child of a Mirror object in Swift

Tags: swift, dynamic, reflection, types, mirror

I am trying to understand why I am unable to create an instance of a class using a mirror in Swift.  In the playground, everything seems fine until the very last line of code below.

So, here's the first example with the use of type(of:):

```
// First Example
var s = String( "Foo" ) // Playground Output: Foo
type(of: s) // Playground Output:  String.Type
var typeClone = type( of: s ).init() // Playground Output: "" (as expected)
```

Everything works as expected.  Now, when I try to do this same sort of thing with a child found in a mirror object, the playground complains:

```
// Second Example
class FooContainer {
   var s : String = "Foo"
}

var t = FooContainer()
var tMirror = Mirror( reflecting: t ) // Output: Mirror for FooContainer
tMirror.children.first! // Output: {some "s"}, value "Foo")

type( of: tMirror.children.first!.value ) // Output: String.Type
var typeClone2 = type( of: tMirror.children.first!.value ).init()
```

The line with "typeClone2" is the one that fails.  If I break down the expressions and inspect things, it seems like all of the types and values are similar, as in the first example.  But in the second case, the playground emits this error:

Playground execution failed:

> error: Type Playground.playground:12:18: error: 'init' is a member of the >type; use 'type(of: ...)' to initialize a new object of the same dynamic >type
>   var typeClone2 = type( of: tMirror.children.first!.value ).init()
>                   ^
>                                                             type(of:  )

What do I have to do to make this work?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code won't work but the error you get is wrong so you should ignore it.

The real problem is you can't just blindly call `init()` on the type of an `Any`. There are a lot of types that don't have an `init()` at all. It works on `type(of: s)` in your first example because the compiler knows at compile-time that the type is `String` (and that `String` has an `init()`). But if you wrap it in `Any` then it fails as well:

```
let s = String("Foo") as Any
let typeClone = type(of: s).init()
```

Unfortunately this means there's no way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you.  I accepted the answer because it cleanly details why the code doesn't work.  Is there another, alternative way of extracting the type information at runtime so I can create an object of a similar type, manipulate it, and then stash it somewhere again as an Any?  Thanks again.

Comment: The only way to do that would be to declare a protocol that defines appropriate methods for doing whatever copying + manipulation you want, and then adopting that protocol on all types that you want to be able to manipulate.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this for posterity. I realise this is an OLD question now, but in recent versions we now have a way to achieve this.

A great source that explains the whole thing is here: https://www.pointfree.co/blog/posts/78-reverse-engineering-swiftui-s-navigationpath-codability

> To save the reader though, `_typeByName("")` returns the type as an `Any`

Note its **not private API** – it is internal (note the underscore) so its discouraged but generally safe and commonly used (including by ).